# Uniform Existence of a Generalized Solution (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $K\subset U$ be compact, and $f : [t_0, t_0 + T]\times U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a  Caratheodory function. Show that there exist $\tau > 0$, which may depend on $K$, such that the initial-value problem
    $$
  \begin{cases}
   x'(t) = f(t, x(t)),\qquad t>0,\\
   x(t_0) = x_0,
  \end{cases}
 $$
has a generalized solution on $[t_0, t_0 + \tau]$ for every $x_0 \in K$.

From a theorem, for **any** $x_0 \in U$, there exists $\tau$ such that the ODE has a generalized solution in the interval $[t_0, t_0 + \tau]$. The value of $\tau$ may depend on the chosen $x_0$.

So for such $\tau$ to be applicable to all $x_0 \in K$, I am thinking of taking its *infimum* and prove the existence of a generalized solution in the obtained interval. **BUT** I did not use the assumption of $K$ being compact which makes me really doubt my train of thought. Guide me on how to prove this please. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you take $x_0\in U$, there exist $\tau>0$ and a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that for any $x_1$ in that neighborhood the solution satisfying $x(t_0)=x_1$ is defined at least on $[t_0,t_0+\tau]$.